# Styling of wikipedia?printable=yes article

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am integrating wikipedia articles dynamically via **iframe** to my web application. The `?printable=yes` parameter hides the menu, example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?printable=yes

Now my question is if Wikipedia supports further styling which can be linked? I know you can create a Wikipedia account and overwrite styles for that logged-in user, but how would I apply this custom style (via URL parameter for example) for other users. Is that possible?

If not, do you know of any trick to style a cross origin iframe? Or which Wiki API would query the full text and images via a JSON endpoint?

Comment: It is possible to do so using a browser extension, however I believe it won't solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible to add a custom style for anonymous users, like what you can do for logged in by adding styles to a User:MyName/common.js page.

But you can specify a script using ?useskin= parameter, like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein?useskin=timeless.

Comment: What scripts/ skins are available and is it possible to add a public (which everyone can reference) one?

Comment: A quick api request: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=siteinfo&formatversion=2&siprop=skins